# Getting Unbound Local Error while accessing a database in Flask with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a simple flask web application that records the local user time and user agent strings, and posts it via ajax to the database (`userdatabase.db`) which I create separately on the python interpretor (with Python3).

Here is my templates/home.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type=text/javascript>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     console.log('Date Being Posted'); // this will fire at first
       $.ajax({

            url:"{{url_for('home')}}",
            clock: new Date(),
            type = 'POST',
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
       });
    });

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>    
    <p>Recording time!</p>

    {% for user in users %}
    <p>{{user.clock}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my main file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from sqlalchemy import exc
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


project_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#path to the database
database_file = "sqlite:///{}".format(os.path.join(project_dir, "userdatabase.db"))

app = Flask(__name__)

#indicate to the web application where the database will be stored
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file

#initialize a connection to the database; use the db variable to interact with the databse
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

##define a model for the user

class User(db.Model):

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_agent = db.Column(db.String(1024), index=True)
    clock = db.Column(db.String(1024), index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User-Agent: {}, Clock: {}".format(self.user_agent, self.clock)

@app.route("/home", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():

    if request.method == "POST":

        user_agent_received = request.headers.get('User-Agent')
        clock_received = request.json['clock']
        user = User(user_agent=user-agent_received, clock=clock_received)
        print (user)
        try:
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        except exc.IntegrityError as e:
            db.session().rollback()

        users = User.query.all()

    return render_template("home.html", users=users)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The commands I used to create the database were:

`from main import db`

`db.create_all()`

But when I run the `main.py` file, I am getting the following error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'users' referenced before assignment`

I see no errors being shown inside the console, which I believe would have been the case had their been some errors in posting data from `AJAX`. I am new to `flask`, and created this code mostly by following online tutorials. Could anyone please help what could be going wrong over here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code

```
users = User.query.all()
```

outside  (before)  the block

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

This is because if the `request.method == "GET"`, then the variable users is not defined

Note the code

```
return render_template("home.html", users=users)
```

only runs if the request method is NOT POST in your current code
So alternatively, indent that line to run when the method is POST (in which case you might get the error that your view did not return a response when Method is GET)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer Moses! It works now! But now have a `500 Internal Server` error which seems to be due to Ajax. The original error has been resolved though!